# Kotlin coroutines return String

Tags: android, kotlin, android-asynctask, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

I am trying to convert a method from java to kotlin and replace `AsyncTask` with coroutines, but I do not know how to return value from coroutines

This is my method

```
override fun getCompressedVideo(context:Context ,video: Uri) {

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {

            val inputFile = video.getRealPathFromVideoUri(context)
            val loadJNI: LoadJNI = LoadJNI();
            try {

                val workFolder: String = context.filesDir.absolutePath

                val outputFile: String = getFileFullName(
                    FilesConstants.VIDEO_FOLDER,
                    String.format(FilesConstants.VIDEO_NAME_FILE_FORMAT, System.currentTimeMillis())
                );

                val complexCommand = arrayOf (
                    "ffmpeg", "-y"
                    , "-i", inputFile
                    , "-strict", "experimental"
                    , "-s", "320x240"
                    , "-r", "25"
                    , "-aspect", "4:3"
                    , "-ab", "48000"
                    , "-ac", "2"
                    , "-vcodec", "mpeg4"
                    , "-movflags", "+faststart"
                    , "-ar", "22050"
                    , "-b", "2097k"
                    , outputFile);

                loadJNI.run(complexCommand, workFolder, context);
                return outputFile

            } catch (th: Throwable) {
                return@launch
            }
        }
    }
```

the line of **return outputFile** makes compilation error, can anyone please help, it is my first time to use coroutines

**EDIT**

here is the method after using suspend, but now I do not know how I can return value if any problem happen

```
override suspend fun getCompressedVideo(context: Context, video: Uri) {

        val outputFile = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

            val inputFile = video.getRealPathFromVideoUri(context)
            val loadJNI: LoadJNI = LoadJNI();
            try {

                val workFolder: String = context.filesDir.absolutePath

                val outputFile: String = getFileFullName(
                    FilesConstants.VIDEO_FOLDER,
                    String.format(FilesConstants.VIDEO_NAME_FILE_FORMAT, System.currentTimeMillis())
                );

                val complexCommand = arrayOf(
                    "ffmpeg", "-y"
                    , "-i", inputFile
                    , "-strict", "experimental"
                    , "-s", "320x240"
                    , "-r", "25"
                    , "-aspect", "4:3"
                    , "-ab", "48000"
                    , "-ac", "2"
                    , "-vcodec", "mpeg4"
                    , "-movflags", "+faststart"
                    , "-ar", "22050"
                    , "-b", "2097k"
                    , outputFile
                );

                loadJNI.run(complexCommand, workFolder, context)
            }catch (th: Throwable) {
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 2**

you mean like this

```
override suspend fun getCompressedVideo(context: Context, video: Uri) : String {

        try {
            val retValue = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

                val inputFile = video.getRealPathFromVideoUri(context)
                val loadJNI: LoadJNI = LoadJNI()

                val workFolder: String = context.filesDir.absolutePath

                val outputFile: String = getFileFullName(
                    FilesConstants.VIDEO_FOLDER,
                    String.format(FilesConstants.VIDEO_NAME_FILE_FORMAT, System.currentTimeMillis())
                )

                val complexCommand = arrayOf(
                    "ffmpeg", "-y"
                    , "-i", inputFile
                    , "-strict", "experimental"
                    , "-s", "320x240"
                    , "-r", "25"
                    , "-aspect", "4:3"
                    , "-ab", "48000"
                    , "-ac", "2"
                    , "-vcodec", "mpeg4"
                    , "-movflags", "+faststart"
                    , "-ar", "22050"
                    , "-b", "2097k"
                    , outputFile
                )

                loadJNI.run(complexCommand, workFolder, context)
            }

            return retValue.toString()
        } catch (th: Throwable) {
            return ""
        }
    }
```

and call it like

```
GlobalScope.launch {
            val retValue = ffmpegFacade.getCompressedVideo(this@TestActivity, Uri.parse(""))
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you expect this function

```
override fun getCompressedVideo(context: Context, video: Uri)
```

to return when the compression is already done, this is not how it can work. Your code launches a concurrent task that will complete at some arbitrary time after your `getCompressedVideo` has returned.

Instead, I think you should approach it as follows:

```
override suspend fun getCompressedVideo(
        context: Context, video: Uri
): String? = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    try {
        val inputFile = video.getRealPathFromVideoUri(context)
        val loadJNI = LoadJNI()
        val workFolder: String = context.filesDir.absolutePath
        val outputFile: String = getFileFullName(
                FilesConstants.VIDEO_FOLDER,
                String.format(FilesConstants.VIDEO_NAME_FILE_FORMAT,
                        System.currentTimeMillis())
        )
        val complexCommand = arrayOf("-i", inputFile, "other-params")
        loadJNI.run(complexCommand, workFolder, context);
        outputFile
    } catch (t: Throwable) {
        null
    }
}
```

As you can see, this means changing the declaration of `getCompressedVideo` to a `suspend fun`. You can't call it directly from an Android callback. So, at the call site, write

```
this.launch {
    val videoFile = ffmpegfacade.getCompressedVideo(context, Uri.parse("example.org/video"))
    // continue processing on the UI thread using videoFile
}
```

Here take note that we call `launch` with `this` as the receiver. The receiver of `launch` must be a `CoroutineScope` and you should implement it in your `MainActivity` or whatever is the context you're calling it from. See [structured concurrency](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html#structured-concurrency) for an explanation.

Comment: what should I return in the catch , there will not be value to return, please check my edit above and tell me if that is what you meant or not

Comment: In your new code you return nothing from `getCompressedVideo` in any case. I'm not sure what your goal is if you did it like that. My version shows a function that returns `String` and throws any exceptions that occur in the block. You can use the plain-old `try-catch` on the call site to catch them, or if you prefer, you can catch them inside the function and return whatever you like. Just like you would in plain code.

Comment: this method should be used to take video uri and read it and compress it using ffmpeg and save it to memory and return the new uri of the compressed video

Comment: so what you mean that I need to change the method and make it return String value, in the try I should return outputfile and in catch I should return null for example, is that you mean ?

Comment: Yes, `null` if that works for you. But oftentimes exceptions are better for the case where something doesn't succeed. The main point is that the choices you have are identical as if it was a plain, non-suspendable function. Both on the call side and on the implementation side.

Comment: please check my Edit 2

Comment: Yes, something like that, but see my updated answer. You don't need the `return` statement, nor do you need to assign the result of `withContext` to a variable. What you _do_ need to do is implement structured concurrency and avoid calling `GlobalScope.launch`. This was already covered in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible ways to solve it is to use `GlobalScope.async` builder:

```
fun getCompressedVideo() = GlobalScope.async {
    val outputFile: String = "" 

    // ... compress video

    outputFile
}

// Calling getCompressedVideo() from outside
fun compressVideoAsync() {
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        val compression = getCompressedVideo()
        val outputFile = compression.await() // wait for result of compression operation without blocking the main thread

        // outputFile is ready to use
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a Kotlin [function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html) return type like so:

```
override fun getCompressedVideo(context: Context, video: Uri): String {
```

However you still can't because it's asynchronous, a function is synchronous.

To return from the method it would have to wait until it is complete, which goes against the whole purpose of doing it asynchronously.

You can instead use a [high-order function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#higher-order-functions) to specify what to do with the data once the async task has been completed.

```
override fun getCompressedVideo(context:Context ,video: Uri, action: (String?) -> Unit) {

    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {

        val inputFile = video.getRealPathFromVideoUri(context)
        val loadJNI: LoadJNI = LoadJNI();
        try {

            val workFolder: String = context.filesDir.absolutePath

            val outputFile: String = getFileFullName(
                FilesConstants.VIDEO_FOLDER,
                String.format(FilesConstants.VIDEO_NAME_FILE_FORMAT, System.currentTimeMillis())
            );

            val complexCommand = arrayOf (
                "ffmpeg", "-y"
                , "-i", inputFile
                , "-strict", "experimental"
                , "-s", "320x240"
                , "-r", "25"
                , "-aspect", "4:3"
                , "-ab", "48000"
                , "-ac", "2"
                , "-vcodec", "mpeg4"
                , "-movflags", "+faststart"
                , "-ar", "22050"
                , "-b", "2097k"
                , outputFile);

            loadJNI.run(complexCommand, workFolder, context);
            action(outputFile)

        } catch (th: Throwable) {
            action(null)
        }
    }
}
```